# How can I monitor/know which activity/view is currently running on the testing device?

Tags: android

**I am debugging an android app and wanted to know how can I monitor the current activity or view that is being running on the testing device, So I can debug easily.

Note: I have not written the app, that's why I am asking the question.

Thanks**

Comment: Name your test methods accordingly

Comment: I just wanted to monitor which activity or "class" is currently running

Comment: Install this app -> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.willme.topactivity&hl=en